# Retrieving a static pointer from a closed-source library, not exposed by the public interface

Tags: c++, memory

I am using a dll which code I cannot change. I have a public interface that exposes a class `Surface` that I am using.

The code of the dll contains something similar to this:

```
static Texture  staticTexture[MAXTEXTURECOUNT];
static Texture *staticTextureCurrent = NULL;
static Texture *staticGetTextureById(int id);

class Texture
{
public:
    int     _id;

...
    void   *_dib;
...
};

void Surface::DrawSetTexture(int id)
{
    Texture *texture = staticGetTextureById(id);
    staticTextureCurrent = texture;
}
```

The Texture class is not exposed in any way by the public header files. I need to access the memory that is being pointed to by Texture::_dib. Ideally I would want to be able to call `staticGetTextureById` from anywhere, but the memory is what I am after.
I do however know more or less how the Texture class looks like.

I already tried to see if I can recover the Texture pointer by fiddling with the cpu registers after a call to DrawSetTexture, but that didn't work out at all.

Any ideas how to retrieve this pointer? I would be glad about any solution no matter how hacky as long as it doesn't crash and works somewhat reliably. I need a faster way to draw to that memory then with what I am given.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, classes operate similarly to structs in C in terms of how they're set up. So, perhaps by doing ptrToClassObject+offset it might just work. There's a way to get the offset of the class members, I just don't know anything about how that's set up.

Comment: I don't think that works, for multiple reasons: 1. I don't exactly know the current code. I have some rather old code. 2. The function itself is static and not part of the class itself, so it shouldn't be exposed like that.